# how to split strings using Java ?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

i tried to split a string looks like this

```
<a><b><c></c></b></a>
```

with java using the following code

```
String[] s =input.split("[<>]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

and this was the output

```
[, a, b, c, /c, /b, /a]
```

i don't know what should i do to get rid of this empty string in the beginning of the resulting array.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you're dealing with XML, you'll better off using the appropriate XML tools.

Comment: actually i faced this problem in a programming contest ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an alternative method using regular expression matching:

```
String input = "<a><b><c></c></b></a>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(.+?)>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();

while(m.find())
    s.add(m.group(1));

System.out.println(s.toString());
```

**Output:**
[a, b, c, /c, /b, /a]

Answer (score 1):

It's normally. If you want to remove first empty element use next:

```
    String input = "<a><b><c></c></b></a>";
    String[] strs = input.split("[<>]+");
    String[] s =Arrays.copyOfRange(strs, 1, strs.length);
```

Or go in cycle looking for empty elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for using Google Guava library, then [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) has a neat way to omit empty strings using `Splitter#omitEmptyStrings()`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through all the elements to get rid of the empty ones..

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the input format you can do:

```
String[] s =input.substring(1).split("[<>]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

Comment: yes i am sure ... but my question is shall i do it explicitly ?? or there is some other way .. like changing this pattern maybe ?

Comment: not really. split will always return something before the first match, unless there's no match when it will return the whole string